# When I create a relative symbolic link to node_modules I can't start the vuejs app

Tags: npm, terminal, vue.js

In order to avoid `npm install` each time, I used to create a relative symbolic link to a general node_modules: `ln -s <dest> <link>`.

I did this within a project which is generated by [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli), then I input `npm run dev` as usual, everything worked well:[image]

Everything worked well until I opened the http://localhost:8080 on the browser, I see a blank page, and develop tool told me that:

[image]

Comment: you should not do that.

Comment: I'm in China,  `npm install` is unstable, sometimes doesn't work. Although not everyone in here like me.

Comment: If that is the case you might want to think about using `yarn` since it actually caches the installed nodes which helps if you have a flaky connection. It still has bugs though so you should check if it fits your project.

Comment: I will try, thx